# How can I serve queues in several Laravel projects at once?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

How can I maintain independent queues of different Laravel projects in one place? (except Laravel Horizon) Maybe there will be some ideas on how to do this...

Comment: You can use same Redis server for different projects.